# My url data isn't passing to my codeigniter controller's function

Tags: codeigniter, variables, uri, codeigniter-url

The domain I'm using is `http://www.domainname.com/admin/users/edit/1`

```
class Cal_Admin extends Controller {

function Cal_Admin()
{
    parent::Controller();   
    $this->load->model('events/model_events');
    $this->load->model('users/model_users');
}

function index()
{
    $data['events'] = $this->model_events->get_home_entries();
    $data['users'] = $this->model_users->_get_all();
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_head');
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_menu');
    $this->load->view('admin/admin',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_foot');
}

function users($action=NULL, $uid=NULL)
{
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_head');
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_menu');
    $segments = $this->uri->total_segments();

    switch ($action) {
        case "add" :
            $this->load->view('admin/users/form');
        break;
        case "edit" :
            $data['user'] = $this->model_users->_get_user($uid);
            $this->load->view('admin/users/form',$data);
        break;
        default:
            $data['users'] = $this->model_users->_get_all();
            $data['action'] = $action;
            $this->load->view('admin/users',$data);
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_foot');
}
```

Comment: Your classname is Cal_Admin, but in the url it's admin

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it myself.

I had the uri library redeclared in the autoload.php file.  I know the cal_admin was the class and I was using it in the url, i took it out for some reason in the example.